# How to I use JSR223 module in a Flatpak installed JMeter?

Tags: flatpak

I have a perfectly working JMeter script that uses a JSR223 sampler to calculate some variables.

Now when I install JMeter via Flatpak this module simply doesn't run (or at least the variables aren't there.  I tried to allow all permissions on Flatseal and the result was the same.

Anyone knows why is this ?